Movie about a locked gated community with cameras everywhere
I'm trying to remember this movie. Anyone have any ideas?
It's an American thriller and I think it's from the late 80s but it MIGHT be early 90s.
A family get invited to live in a new gated community where the father starts work (I think he was an architect or somebody that installs security systems).
After a short while the family start to notice things aren't quite right in the community.
The guy that owns the place has private cameras set up in his house/office from every room in every house in the community.
The kids are all perfect, polite, tidy, good school grades etc.
The family's dog goes missing. It is returned the next day but it has had its voice box removed so it can't bark.
That's all I can remember. Hope someone can help me :)

The Stepford Wives?

I just checked a trailer for that. Unfortunately that isnt the one im looking for :(

I checked both trailers.. nothing like it.

This also sounds a bit like the episode "Community"of the show "Fear Itself" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_(Fear_Itself)

Sounds like The Colony from 1995 with John Ritter.

Following a carjacking, a man and his family move into an Orwellian-like gated community where the billionaire owner controls the residents' lives. There are draconian rules, armed guards all over, and cameras in all the rooms. Then sinister things begin to happen.

Their dog's vocal cords are removed for barking at night. Here's a clip where the mom is knocked out:




OMG!! Thats it. Ty soooo much, you rock. (Dont suppose you know the answer to my smarthouse film too?) Lol

@SaraLukas I think I do and just commented on it. See if it's the same one from that old answer.
